# Cross-Compile Rust with libdbus for ARM

Tags: linux, rust, arm, cross-compiling

i'm currently trying to cross-compile a Rust application on x86 for ARM. The application uses the bluer crate and depends on dbus. But when i'm trying to compile I get following error:

```
= note: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know WHY the error occurs (libdbus is compiled for x86 and therefore not compatible with the target architecture) but I don't know how to fix that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a recipe [here](https://github.com/cross-rs/wiki_assets/tree/main/FAQ/dbus) that allows you to compile rust projects that depend on libdbus using rust-cross.